# Using Database View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, lambda, viewmodel

I want to combine some of Database tables in a **Database View** and retrieve it as an Entity class like I did for Tables. Let'a say I have **Student** and **City** tables and StudentView in my database for example. In this scene:

1) Should I create an **Entity** for **StudentView** as I do for **Student** and **City** tables?

2) Of course ViewModel can be considered instead of using View (so that not needing and extra Entity). But, for some limitations or not enough knowledge about Lambda or Linq, is it acceptable using Database View instead of ViewModel in MVC?

3) I want to show some data on my Dropdownlist like below by combining 3-4 fields:
Michael Damn (01 Jun 1980 - London)

So, is it better to combine these field in Database View rather than Controller or Model? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You better create a new model StudentView ( that should not be an entity - so need not to be a derived from dbContext ) you can write in your repository as below,

```
public IQueryable<StudentView> GetSudents()
{
   using (var db = new StudentDb())
   {
       var results=from student in Students
                   from city in City
                   where student.CityId==city.Id
                   select new StudentView { Name = student.Name, Id = student.Id, CityName=city.Name };
       return results;
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try it and inform you. But, before trying it could you please clarify me about the other points above? Could you also reply them by updating your answer? I think we can use database View in order to displaying the data rather than Insert/Update/Delete operations. Is that true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried, but it did not work due to not using properly. Could you explain a little bit more what I should do step by step please?